# Add class to a li with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, addclass

I am trying to add a class to a label of a `<input type="radio" />` on the click event of the label with jQuery.

```
$(".gallery ul li input").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var lblid = ".gallery ul li";
        var inplb = ".gallery ul li input";

        if ($(inplb).is(":checked")) {
            $(lblid).addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $(lblid).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

and html

```
<div class="gallery">
  <ul>
   <li><span></span><label for="slim1"><img  src="../boo/img/banks_03.png" alt="" /></label><input type="radio" id="slim1" name="slim1" /></li>
   <li><span></span><label for="slim2"><img src="../boo/img/banks_05.png" alt="" /></label><input type="radio" id="slim2" name="slim2" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the class will not apply?

Comment: Your code works well http://jsbin.com/ocanar/1/ what's the problem ? Is the code executing ? Make sure you have included the jQuery library above this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radio's change event will be triggered when clicking the label :

```
$(".gallery ul li input").on('change', function () {
    $(".gallery ul li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttjgp/1/)

Comment: .gallery ul li.active img{
  border:#b1b1b1 1px solid;
  width:121px;
  height:54px;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$(".gallery ul li input").on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GdjUa/1/)